# How to have multiple tabbed sections open the first tab on load using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added multiple tabbed sections to my webpage but I am having trouble making sure the second tabbed section also opens up the first tab on load. I am currently following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) tutorial from W3Schools and this is my code on W3Schools so far:

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<p>In this example, we use JavaScript to "click" on the London button, to open the tab on page load.</p>

<!--first tab-->

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<!--second tab-->

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '1')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '2')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '3')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

I have managed to create a second tabbed section underneath the first one but I cannot get both tabbed sections to show the first tab on page load at the same time.

Comment: The issue is that you have 2 elements with the same ID, `defaultOpen` This is not valid HTML and it is the reason only the first tab set is working(JavaScript will just target the first instance of that ID).

Answer (score 2):

Use class-names instead of ids for cityes. Add a "show" class-name to the active content:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (var i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].classList.remove('show');
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (var i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName(cityName)[0].classList.add('show');
  document.getElementsByClassName(cityName)[1].classList.add('show');
  var cuttentTabClass = evt.currentTarget.className.split(" ")[1];
  console.log(cuttentTabClass);
  document.getElementsByClassName(cuttentTabClass)[0].classList.add('active');
  document.getElementsByClassName(cuttentTabClass)[1].classList.add('active');
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.tabcontent.show {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>In this example, we use JavaScript to "click" on the London button, to open the tab on page load.</p>

<!--first tab-->

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks l" onclick="openCity(event, 'london')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks p" onclick="openCity(event, 'paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks t" onclick="openCity(event, 'tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent london">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent paris">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div class="tabcontent tokyo">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<!--second tab-->

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks l" onclick="openCity(event, 'london')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks p" onclick="openCity(event, 'paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks t" onclick="openCity(event, 'tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent london">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent paris">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div class="tabcontent tokyo">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is really close to what I'm looking for but once I click "Paris" on the first tabbed section, the second tabbed section also switches to the Paris tab. Would you be willing to help me figure out how I can have these two tabbed sections be independent of one another? Like if I pressed "Paris" on the first tabbed section, the second tabbed section would still stay on "London"?

Comment: @catjh the tutorial you have chosen to follow is not suited for your purpose. I don't think that your script can be reliably changes to obtain what you need. You need *an entirely new* script.

Comment: Understood! I'm not very familiar with JavaScript but I did have an idea in mind and wanted to see if I could execute it. I will try and find a better solution. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @catjh You can use **[this](https://github.com/Ajax30/eztabs)** jQuery plugin for as many independent instances as you need. It is easy to use. If instead what you want is to *learn*, find a better tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I needed two divs to show when a certain tab was clicked and this did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery solution. It uses a small (jQuery) plugin. I hope that helps.

```js
/*
 * EZ Tabs
 * by Razvan Zamfir
 */
! function(i) {
  i.fn.eztabs = function(n) {
    var a = i.extend({
      tabsList: ".ez_tabs",
      boxContainer: ".ez_content",
      animation: "none",
      animationTime: 500,
      fullWidthTabs: !0
    }, n);
    return this.each(function() {
      var n = this,
        t = a.tabsList,
        e = a.boxContainer;
      a.fullWidthTabs === !0 && i(t).addClass("fullwidth");
      var s = i(n).find(e).children();
      i(s).hide(), i(s[0]).show();
      var o = i(n).find(t).children("li");
      i(o[0]).addClass("active"), i(o).each(function(n) {
        i(this).on("click", function() {
          i(this).addClass("active"), i(o).not(this).removeClass("active");
          var t = i(s[n]);
          return "none" === a.animation ? (i(s).hide(), i(t).show()) : "slideUpDown" === a.animation ? (i(s).slideUp(a.animationTime), i(t).slideDown(a.animationTime)) : "slideLeftRight" === a.animation && (i(e).css("overflow", "hidden"), i(s).css({
            width: "100%",
            display: "none"
          }), i(s).animate({
            marginLeft: "-110%"
          }, a.animationTime), i(t).css("display", "block").animate({
            marginLeft: "0"
          }, a.animationTime)), !1
        })
      })
    })
  }
}(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('.tabset').eztabs({
    animation: 'slideUpDown',
    animationTime: 200
  });
});
```

```css
.tabset {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
ul.ez_tabs {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    height: 31px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.ez_tabs li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 !important;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 8px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);    
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);    
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5', GradientType=0);
}
ul.ez_tabs li.active {
    color: #111;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.ez_content {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
article {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #222;
    background: #fff;
}
article ul {
    margin: 0;
}
article p,
article ul li {
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
}
article p {
    text-align: justify;
}

/* Full width tabs */

ul.ez_tabs.fullwidth {
    display: flex;
}
ul.ez_tabs.fullwidth li {
    -webkit-flex: 1; 
    -ms-flex: 1;    
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabset">
  <ul class="ez_tabs">
    <li>Description</li>
    <li>Delivery</li>
    <li>Composition</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="ez_content">
    <article>
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabset">
  <ul class="ez_tabs">
    <li>Description</li>
    <li>Delivery</li>
    <li>Composition</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="ez_content">
    <article>
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can add *your own styles*, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I was taking a gander at your code. And it looks like the issue is that you are using the same ID for both tabs. ID's should be unique.

Comment: I tried changing the second tabbed section's tablinks id to defaultOpen2 and added "document.getElementById("defaultOpen2").click();" in the script but now the second tabbed section shows the first tab and the first tabbed section is completely closed. Though I may have gotten something confused; were you referring to another id?

Comment: My assumption that the document.getElementById().click() would work with multiple IDs was incorrect! user7412419 has a great suggestion with adding a class to the tabs that you want to display on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems

1. You have 2 elements with the same id so the code just select the
   first
2. You are using same classes for all tabs and content use different classes name for each panel
3. You hide all content every time to click on button, you should use separate functions or better make on dynamic function

Answer (score 0):

As Megabyter said, both ids need to be unique. However, your click function hides all of the 'tabcontent' `div`s. Therefore, calling `.click()` for two unique ids will only show the second tab's content (because the second `.click()` will hide the content shown by the first). I would suggest just adding the class `.active` to the two tab contents you want to show on page load in your HTML and then adding in your CSS the class `display: block` to `.active`. That would also allow you in your function to just add the class `.active` and not worry about changing the display style in the Javascript.

**Edit**

You also need some way for your function to distinguish between the two tabbed sections and only change the section clicked. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G5N25FZAD0KE) is a working example.

1. I added two container `<div>`s with `num` attributes so the function can distinguish them. This number is passed in as the third argument in the `openCity()` function. The function loops through the two containers, and only edits the container where the number passed into the function equals the `num` attribute of the container.
2. The child tab content `<div>`s and tab links of the correct container are retrieved by calling `.getElementsByClassName()` for both [See here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp)
3. Then the function loops through the child tab contents and tab links (only the ones in the correct container `<div>`) and removes the class `.active` from them.
4. Finally, the second parameter was changed to a number (instead of an id). The number is equal to 1, 2, and 3 respectively for both sets of tab links. This number is used to find the correct child tab link and its corresponding tab content within the correct container and add the class `.active` to them.

P.S. You do not have to define the variable `i` for a `for` loop. `for` loops do it all for you. `while` loops require defining the variable beforehand and incrementing it within the loop after every iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did try adding a .active class and it does seem like both the first tabs in each of the tabbed sections are showing up. However, when I click on the second tab in the first tabbed section, it closes the first tab in the second tabbed section. I've added a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G5M8AL7MQYHO) to the code.