# Problem with buttons in module tags system

Tags: html, css

I need advice on one mistake. On my page, which I do, I have modules and theories, and it's all in the tag system so that you can switch those modules with the theory, but the buttons on those tablinks so they pop and always move above each other instead of being next to each other. I did not find the error anywhere, so I would need advice, in my opinion it will not be a mistake in css but in something else but I'm not sure, thank you in advance for your help.

I will attach examples of the image with the problem below the code.

HTML Code:

```
<button class="tablinks react-to-dark" onclick="openModule(event, 'morse', 'morse-theory')" id="defaultOpen" >Morseovka</button>
    <button class="tablinks react-to-dark" onclick="openModule(event, 'ascii', 'ascii-theory')">ASCII</button>
    
    <div id="module">
        <div id="morse" class="tabcontent">
            {% include 'modules/morse-code.html' %}
        </div>

        <div id="ascii" class="tabcontent">
            {% include 'modules/ascii.html' %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="theory">
        <div id="morse-theory" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Moseovka</h3>
            <p>Morseova abeceda je skupina symbolů, která je používána v telegrafii. Kóduje znaky latinské abecedy, číslice a speciální znaky <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">do kombinací krátkých a dlouhých signálů. Ty je možné přenášet na dálku jednodušším způsobem než všechny znaky abecedy. K přenosu morseovky je možné použít zvukový signál, elektrický signál (telegraf), optický signál (signalizace vlajkami, záznam na papír pomocí teček a čárek, světelné záblesky). 
                Nejběžnější použití je dnes v amatérské radiotelegrafii. Rychlost komunikace se pohybuje od 60 do 250 znaků za minutu.</span></p>
                <button onclick="readMore(this)" class="readmore" class="theory-btn">Číst dále</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="theory">
        <div id="ascii-theory" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>ASCII</h3>
            <p>ASCII tabulka je číselné vyjádření znaků abecedy a znaků používaných k zápisu textu, čísel, apod. Kód ASCII je podle původní definice <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">sedmibitový, obsahuje tedy 128 platných znaků. 
                Pro potřeby dalších jazyků a pro rozšíření znakové sady se používají osmibitová rozšíření ASCII kódu, která obsahují dalších 128 kódů.</span></p>
                <button onclick="readMore(this)" class="readmore" class="theory-btn">Číst dále</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.tablinks {
    outline: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #04c4d911;
    border: solid 6px $cyan0;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 3em;
    padding-right: 3em;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 1em 1em 0% 0%;
}

.tablinks:hover {
    background-color: #04c4d93a;
}

.tablinks:active {
    background-color: #04c4d99c;
}
```

JS Code:

```
function openModule(evt, moduleId, theoryId) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(moduleId).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

  document.getElementById(theoryId).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

window.onload = function(e){ 
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
}
```

The problem here is the tag card has moved up and I don't know why:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs)

Comment: I've seen this before and tried everything, it works as it should, but only the button always moves up. @Kunal Tanwar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here I made it easy for you.**

```js
function openCity(cityName, className) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
            .id {
                width: 600px !important;
                margin-left: 10px !important;

            }

            .tb {
                    border: 5px solid #27C4D9 !important;
                border-top-left-radius: 17px;
                border-top-right-radius: 17px;
                border-bottom: none !important;
                background-color: #04c4d911 !important;
                height: 35px !important;
            }

            .mc {
                border: 6px solid #27C4D9 !important;
                background-color: #04c4d911 !important;
                 
            }

            p {
                color: red;
            }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

        <body>
            <div class="id">
                <div class="w3-container">
                    <h2>Tabs</h2>

                </div>

                <div>
                    <button class=" w3-button tb" style=" width: 100px !important;" onclick="openCity('London', 'city')">London</button>
    &nbsp;
    <button class="w3-button tb" style=" width: 150px !important;" onclick="openCity('Paris', 'city')">Paris</button>


                </div>
                <div class="mc">
                    <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
                        <p> Is it everything works fine now if yes so appriciate me. </p>
                        <hr>
                        <h3>Data is here</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
                        <p> Something data which is here goes right here for second tab </p>
                        <hr>
                        <h3>Data is here2</h3>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="id">
                <div class="w3-container">
                    <h2>Tab2</h2>

                </div>

                <div>
                    <button class=" w3-button tb" style=" width: 100px !important;" onclick="openCity('Lon', 'ci')">One more</button>
    &nbsp;
    <button class="w3-button tb" style=" width: 150px !important;" onclick="openCity('Par', 'ci')">Second Tab</button>


                </div>
                <div class="mc">
                    <div id="Lon" class="w3-container ci">
                        <p> All contant changes here no one is duplicated </p>
                        <hr>
                        <h3>Data3</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div id="Par" class="w3-container ci" style="display:none">
                        <p> Something is here I don't know what.   </p>
                        <hr>
                        <h3>Data4</h3>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
```

**I think this is what you want.**

*Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793575/16639239*

Comment: Yes I've seen this but I need the graphic the same as I attached in my question, still and still it doesn't work for me. @Nishant

Comment: ook give me some time I'll be do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would be grateful. @Nishant

Comment: I updated my source code Check it. May be I help you.

Comment: Let me know if my updated code is worked for you.

Comment: The border is a little better there, but the buttons still swap, which I don't want @Nishant

Comment: Now check I updated my source Code It will work for you. Finally It's done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't want to bother you with that anymore, but I just have a little mistake that when I refreshn the page I see everything at once but I want to give defaultOpen to one of the modules so that when I resfreshn I see the module I am set it up.

Comment: I don't know if you understand me, but I just need to set some default position for both the module and the theory so that I don't see everything after refreshing the page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795160/how-to-set-show-a-tab-module-by-default-for-multiple-tabs @Nishant

Answer (score 0):

The border is a little better there, but the buttons still swap, which I don't want @Nishant

[image]

Comment: Can you explain me what border ```px``` you want and what button ```padding``` you want.

Comment: now check I updated my code it will work for you.

Comment: Another problem occurs when I have more such tag systems on one page, so they fight and one always works but the other does not work, especially the default position after refreshing the page does not work. @Nishant

Comment: In my opinion, the problem will probably be that I always have id = "defaultOpen for one tag button, which if there are more of them in one html code so they beat each other, any solution? @Nishant

Comment: https://codepen.io/jakub-mitrega/pen/xxdeYpM 
I put the problem in codepen.io @Nishant

Comment: I really want to help you but I really don't understand what you actually want can you please share Screenshot of the output you need?

Comment: I need both to work on one page because it doesn't work that way, only one works @Nishant

Comment: share output screen what you want. please it's very confusing .

Comment: But I sent a bug I got in codepen.io. https://codepen.io/jakub-mitrega/pen/xxdeYpM

Comment: do you have screenshot what you actually want? because in codepen it's still not understandable

Comment: I sent a reply with a screen shot and an explanation of what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

**This is an example I need, on one page two module tag systems and both work exactly the same.**

[image]

**This is an example that happens to me on a page I have two module tag systems on one template page and only one is functional.**

[image]

**@Nishant** Is that enough? If it's incomprehensible, I'm sorry, and if I do, I'll fix it.

Comment: as shown in this image you need two boxes one after one right?

Comment: Yes, but of course with different content inside

Comment: Now check I update my code and let me know is it what you want?

Comment: No I want to have the same code for each box I just want to change the default settings for each so I don't have to rewrite the code for each new module so just somehow rewrite the id = "defaultOpen" look in my code there it is.

Comment: Don't rewrite it like this? class = "defaultOpen" but it won't work again I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you cannot use same ```ID``` for different work ```ID``` is unique so every unique task you need ```Unique ID```. hope you got your answer.

Comment: If you use ```Same ID``` so if you click on second box it also change content in first box because both have same ```ID```. so I already gave you solution copy & paste it Enjoy.

Comment: But didn't you change that?

Comment: You see my code above I have it a little different than you would look at it please?

Comment: bro this is what you want as output see.. your Images.

Comment: And this time I'm trying last time for you.

Comment: No, you have two functions in one code, I want to have one function, I just want to track the default position for each box so that it works the same.

Comment: ok I'm trying this to make with one function give me some time.

Comment: Bro there is no way if you use one function it's also change the value of first box. you need to create two function. I checked all this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: If you use one function you face problem like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56857898/16639239

Comment: This is exactly the problem, and will I always attribute a new function when I have a new tag box there?

Comment: So I'll do it somehow, I won't delay or bother you, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'll try if I find any solution I'll update my source code don't worry.

Comment: I will also try and think about solving it.

Comment: Bro, I find a solution and it will help you.