# How to create Multi-tab using Javascript with one function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I want to create multi-tab boxes in one page.**

*I have created multi-tab boxes using Javascript but here I use Two functions ()*

**What I want:** *I want to Create multi-tabs boxes on one page using `one javascript function()`.*

**Problem If I create one Javascript function**: *If I select Second One Tab of box2 so it also selects Paris which I don't want I want*.

```js
//Here I use two javascript function 

    function openCity(cityName) {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
            }


            function openCi(cityName) {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ci");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
            }
```

```css
        .id {
            width: 600px !important;
            margin-left: 10px !important;

        }

        .tb {
                border: 5px solid #27C4D9 !important;
            border-top-left-radius: 17px;
            border-top-right-radius: 17px;
            border-bottom: none !important;
            background-color: #04c4d911 !important;
            height: 35px !important;
        }

        .mc {
            border: 6px solid #27C4D9 !important;
            background-color: #04c4d911 !important;
             
        }

        p {
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

    <body>
        <div class="id">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h2>Tabs</h2>

            </div>

            <div>
                <button class=" w3-button tb" style=" width: 100px !important;" onclick="openCity('London')">London</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button class="w3-button tb" style=" width: 150px !important;" onclick="openCity('Paris')">Paris</button>


            </div>
            <div class="mc">
                <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
                    <p> Is it everything works fine now if yes so appriciate me. </p>
                    <hr>
                    <h3>Data is here</h3>
                </div>

                <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
                    <p> Something data which is here goes right here for second tab </p>
                    <hr>
                    <h3>Data is here2</h3>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="id">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h2>Tab2</h2>

            </div>

            <div>
                <button class=" w3-button tb" style=" width: 100px !important;" onclick="openCi('Lon')">One more</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button class="w3-button tb" style=" width: 150px !important;" onclick="openCi('Par')">Second Tab</button>


            </div>
            <div class="mc">
                <div id="Lon" class="w3-container ci">
                    <p> All contant changes here no one is duplicated </p>
                    <hr>
                    <h3>Data3</h3>
                </div>

                <div id="Par" class="w3-container ci" style="display:none">
                    <p> Something is here I don't know what.   </p>
                    <hr>
                    <h3>Data4</h3>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
```

**I want same output but only using one `Javascript function()`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
function openCity(cityName, className) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
}

...

<div>
    <button class=" w3-button tb" style=" width: 100px !important;" onclick="openCity('London', 'city')">London</button>
    &nbsp;
    <button class="w3-button tb" style=" width: 150px !important;" onclick="openCity('Paris', 'city')">Paris</button>
</div>

...

<div>
    <button class=" w3-button tb" style=" width: 100px !important;" onclick="openCity('Lon', 'ci')">One more</button>
    &nbsp;
    <button class="w3-button tb" style=" width: 150px !important;" onclick="openCity('Par', 'ci')">Second Tab</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I add a new parameter that saved the classname. With this parameter I get tabs of specific div. So this code is not affected the other div.

Answer (score 0):

You can add data-btn attributes to your buttons to target the elements ID. Add a helper class set to display: none, something like `.hidden` add this class to the elements you wish to hide initially. Then you can run a conditional that will check if the classList for the target element contains that class, then toggle.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tb')

function openCity(e) {
  let parent = e.target.closest('.id')
  let targetId = e.target.dataset.btn
  let queryEl = parent.querySelector(`#${targetId}`)
  if (queryEl.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    queryEl.classList.toggle('hidden')
  } else {
    queryEl.classList.toggle('hidden')
  }
}

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', openCity)
})
```

```css
.id {
  width: 600px !important;
  margin-left: 10px !important;
}

.tb {
  border: 5px solid #27C4D9 !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 17px;
  border-top-right-radius: 17px;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  background-color: #04c4d911 !important;
  height: 35px !important;
}

.mc {
  border: 6px solid #27C4D9 !important;
  background-color: #04c4d911 !important;
}

p {
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <div class="id">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h2>Tabs</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="w3-button tb" data-btn="London" style="width: 100px !important;">London</button> &nbsp;
      <button class="w3-button tb" data-btn="Paris" style="width: 150px !important;">Paris</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">
      <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
        <p> Is it everything works fine now if yes so appriciate me. </p>
        <hr>
        <h3>Data is here</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city hidden">
        <p> Something data which is here goes right here for second tab </p>
        <hr>
        <h3>Data is here2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="id">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h2>Tab2</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="w3-button tb" data-btn="London-2" style="width: 100px !important;">One more</button> &nbsp;
      <button class="w3-button tb" data-btn="Paris-2" style="width: 150px !important;">Second Tab</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">
      <div id="London-2" class="w3-container city">
        <p> All contant changes here no one is duplicated </p>
        <hr>
        <h3>Data3</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="Paris-2" class="w3-container city hidden">
        <p> Something is here I don't know what. </p>
        <hr>
        <h3>Data4</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. If I got it right, you are trying to implement the tab system using a single reusable function.
I think the best method for this is to use the relative query instead of selecting the tags directly for each tab group.

Here is a simple example—

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs");

for (let j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
  const tabBtns = tabs[j].querySelectorAll(".tab-btn");
  for (let i = 0; i < tabBtns.length; i++) {
    tabBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      for (let sibling of this.parentNode.children) {
        sibling.classList.remove("active");
      }
      this.classList.add("active");
      toggleTab(this, i);
    });
  }
}

function toggleTab(activator, idx) {
  const parent = activator.parentNode.parentNode;
  const tabs = parent.querySelectorAll(".tab");
  for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    if (i === idx) {
      tabs[i].classList.add("active");
    } else {
      tabs[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.tabs {
  background: #EEE;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.tab-btns {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.tab-btn {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-right: -2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-btn.active {
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-bottom-color: #EEE;
}
.tab {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  display: none;
}
.tab.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab-btns">
    <div class="tab-btn active">One</div>
    <div class="tab-btn">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab active">This is tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">This is tab 2</div>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab-btns">
    <div class="tab-btn active">One</div>
    <div class="tab-btn">Two</div>
    <div class="tab-btn">Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab active">This is tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">This is tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">This is tab 3</div>
</div>
```

You can repeat the HTML as many times as you want and it should work just as fine. You have to make sure the number of `.tab-btn` and `.tab` are equal within the same `.tabs` container.

Comment: someone already answered correclty.. but Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: you should always try out multiple solutions, it will help better understand which one is the best overall, or best for your particular use case.

Comment: yeah I also tried your solution too.. but I found his a bit easy so I used his solution. Thanks again buddy for helping me.